# Flyer chat with supabase

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-database

i'm trying to build a chat app using Flyer chat with supabase. But got a problem don't know how to stream the messages with types.Message from Flyer chat.
here's how i got the messages stream;

```dart
    messagesList = SupaFlow.client
        .from('messages')
        .stream(primaryKey: ['room_id'])
        .eq('room_id', widget.roomData['id'])
        .asBroadcastStream();
```

and here's how i try to show the chat

```dart
StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
          stream: messagesList,
          builder: (context, snapshot) => Chat(
            onMessageLongPress: (context, p1) {
              setState(() {
                isMessageDetail = true;
                selectedMessage = p1;
              });
            },
            onBackgroundTap: () {
              print('click');
              setState(() {
                isMessageDetail = false;
              });
            },
            customDateHeaderText: (p0) => _customDateHeaderText(p0),
            dateIsUtc: true,
            dateHeaderThreshold: 86400000,
            bubbleBuilder: _bubbleBuilder,
            theme: const DefaultChatTheme(
                primaryColor: const Color(0xFF399938),
                inputTextColor: Colors.black,
                inputBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                inputContainerDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                        top: BorderSide(color: const Color(0xFF399938)))),
                inputTextCursorColor: Colors.black,
                inputBorderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.zero)),
            messages: _messages,
            onSendPressed: _handleSendPressed,
            onAttachmentPressed: _handleAttachmentPressed,
            onPreviewDataFetched: _handlePreviewDataFetched,
            onMessageTap: _handleMessageTap,
            user: peerUserData,
          ),
        )
```

currently the chat is still using a local variable _messages, not using data from supabase.

have anyone use flyer chat with supabase? how do i get the messages stream?
thanks

Comment: What is  the issue here? You can just get the messages data from the stream and create a List of Messages.